# Add hyperlink to Sharepoint list item

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript, custom-list, client-object-model

I need to add a hyperlink to the Sharepoint (2013) list item in one of the columns or make the list item itself as a link. I don't know how to do this.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Can you please elaborate the requirement with example? Where you want the link? In same list or in different list or somewhere else?

Comment: Have you tried adding a hyperlink field to the list?

Comment: I tried adding a hyperlink field. But how to insert an URL and text to URL using Javascript into that field?

Comment: Or is there a way to add text box to a list item, so that the user enters values in that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your requirements aren't clear, but if you want the list item to direct you somewhere other than the display form page, you can use a calculated column to combine a url and the item name.

The formula would be:

```
="<a href='"&%URL_Field_Name%&"'> "&[%field_name%]&"</a>"
```

Answer (score 4):

You can take input from user in textboxes and on button call JavaScript function to set the URL Field of the list item as given below:

```
var urlValue = new SP.FieldUrlValue();
urlValue.set_url("http://google.com");
urlValue.set_description("my description");
newListItem.set_item("UrlFieldName", urlValue);
```

References:

[SP.ListItem.item Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee549053.aspx)

Comment: This would be the best answer, considering the comment about using javascript.

Comment: @arsalan I`m after a same kind of solution. Please suggest the javascript wherein we want the item name: Apply Now to be shown with the value of the hyperlink. I `ve tried calculated column, but in my case the moment user is checking the details in dispform mode, calculated column code is visible rather than the hyperlink.

Comment: @Jason you can hide the calculated to column to appear in display forms. Check [How to remove title column](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/118181/how-to-remove-title-column-in-sharepoint-2013-list/118184#118184)

Comment: @ArsalanAdamKhatri thanks for your reply. Well I don't to hide the column name, but I want the hyperlink to appear when viewed in MODAL view. Currently, you can view the hylerlink wen u r looking in displayform view, but in modal view it shows the code added in calculated column. Also the calculated column has value set to numeric.

Comment: @Jason you can ask a separate question, please add screenshots for modal view and display form so we can help.