# Add Column which contain a default value "Show details"

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, list-form, out-of-the-box

I want to add a column that contain a default hyperlink value "Show Details". When i click on, i will be redirect to the page of item details that i created with JAVASCRIPT.

Please how to do that?

Comment: Please have a look at https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/134607/add-hyperlink-to-sharepoint-list-item/134621

Comment: How i can use the ID of the lookup in a formula of a calculated column?

Comment: Lookup columns are not available in Calculated column, but workaround: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/208332/use-a-lookup-field-in-a-calculated-column

Comment: Thnx :)The solution is :                         ="<a  target='_blank' href='http://intranet/CA/Restricted/SitePages/Service%20Details.aspx?ProspectID="&ID&"'>Show Details</a>"

Comment: Please post the solution as answer so someone may benefit from it, you will be able to accept it as answer after given time. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is :
Create a calculated Column and make as formula

```
="<a  target='_blank' href='http://intranet/CA/Restricted/SitePages/Service%20Details.aspx?ProspectID="&ID&"'>Show Details</a>"
```